# Impersonate a user at runtime in Kerberos Secured Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, impersonation, kerberos

I have an web application that an receive requests for several other applications running from linux command line as from different users. For each of these requests I have to read data from hdfs for calling application folder which only the calling application linux user access to. Is there a way I can setup configuration in such a way that it can be overridden at run time to impersonate the caller application user for hadoop kerberos authentication.
I have used the code below to create a UserGroupInformation to login from a kerberos keytab.This UGI will act ass the real user and its passed to UserGroupInformation class to create a proxy user as given below.

```
UserGroupInformation realUgi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI("KerberosUser ", "pathToKeytabFile") ;
UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createProxyUser("NewProxyUser", realUgi ); 
ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction() { 
public Void run() throws Exception { 
  Configuration jobconf = new Configuration(); 
  jobconf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://server:hdfsport"); 
  jobconf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "NewroxyUser"); 
  jobconf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "server:jobtracker port"); 
  String[] args = new String[] { "data/input", "data/output" }; 
  ToolRunner.run(jobconf, WordCount.class.newInstance(), args); 
  return null; 
} });
```

I am using a Kerberos secure hadoop implemntation in this case and I am getting an error given below.

```
ERROR UserGroupInformation:1125 - PriviledgedActionException as:NewProxyUser
via KerberosUser cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: User: KerberosUser is not allowed to impersonate NewProxyUser
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: User: KerberosUser is not allowed to impersonate NewProxyUser
```

Can you suggest any other way I can impersonate a Proxy user using Kerberos user.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to setup secure impersonation. Refer the link below for more information http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/Secure_Impersonation.html

Answer (score 0):

To impersonate a caller you must have specific permission to impersonate. I believe that by default only root has this right. I don't know if this can be configured in Linux. (On windows it is `SeImpersonatePrivilege`).

Otherwise users could run random unprivileged services on the Kerberos domain e.g. `http://MYLAPTOP:64990/` and configure them for Kerberos login, and then be able to perform any action on the network as that user.